# JqGrid : Get input text after editing the cell

Tags: jqgrid

> I am trying to provide a note(textbox) for user to leave some
>   messages.

Here is my Jqgrid

```
    $('#confirmTable').jqGrid({
        colModel: confirmTable,
        width: 870,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rowNum: 20,
        loadonce:true
      })
```

Here is the colModel

```
var confirmTable = assignColModel(allColModel,[
{ name: 'storeId', hidden:true, key:true},
{ name: 'storeName', width: 150},
{ name: 'diffBeforeAdjust', width: 80 },
{ name: 'noAdjustAlert', width: 100, editable:true, formatter: 'noAdjustAlertFormatter' }
]);
```

The column 'noAdjustAlert' is using formatter which will return a input tag as following :

```
noAdjustAlertFormatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    if(rowObject.noAdjustAlert=='Y'){
        return  '<input class="form-control input-sm" id="' + rowObject.storeId + 'alertInput" type="text">'
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
```

**Q1** :

> How do I get the input text from user then set it back to the jqgrid?

```
 What I got is always the original value from controller.
```

Could you help me on this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This link to [Guriddo jqGrid documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#unformatting) will give you the answer of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement unformatter which reverses the logic of the formatter.

```
var confirmTable = assignColModel(allColModel,[
    { name: 'storeId', hidden:true, key:true},
    { name: 'storeName', width: 150},
    { name: 'diffBeforeAdjust', width: 80 },
    { name: 'noAdjustAlert', width: 100, editable:true, formatter: 'noAdjustAlertFormatter', unformat:'noAdjustAlertUnFormatter'}
    ]);
```

The write the unformatter in this way

```
var noAdjustAlertUnFormatter: function(inputval , options, cell){
   var inputval = $('input', cell).val();
   return inputval;
}
```

Then you can use getRowData to get the Grid row

```
var row = $('#confirmTable').getRowData(1);
var input value= row.noAdjustAlert;  // This will call the noAdjustAlertUnFormatter if you debug you can see it.
```